# How to login to another site via PHP and download a specific page in the site

Tags: php, html, php-curl

I am trying to write a script to login to a particular site and download a specific webpage in the website.
I have seen some previous questions in stackoverflow , but they seem to be a bit different from my approach.
Up to now, I can download the page which appears just after the login attempt using the following code

```
    <?php
$username='xxxxxx';
$password='xxxxxxxx';
$cookie="/home/cookie.txt";

$url = 'http://mysite/shota/login.php';
$postdata = "?&uname=$username&upwd=$password";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
echo $ch;

$result = curl_exec ($ch);

echo $result;

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

This will output the page which is redirected after a successful login. I am trying to download a page such as

```
`http://mysite/shota/forms/personal_info.php`
```

I have been stuck here for a while. Can someone suggest me the modification needed in this code to fulfill my requirement.Thanks

Comment: _"but they seem to be a bit different from my approach"_ - Then have you tried their approaches instead? You also need to include what your actual issue is. What actually happens when you run your code?

Comment: Yes, actually the above code is also based on combination of answers which appeared earlier

Comment: Php is not the best tool to do this. Use [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) can be easier

Comment: The above code will echo the page which appears after a successful login. But I want to echo a different page

Comment: Then make a new request to that page? The flow will then be: 1. make a request to login and store the cookies. 2. Make a new request (where you pass the stored cookies) to the page you want.

Comment: @Ôrel I am trying to find a solution to this using php as this a part of project which is in the last stage

Comment: @ Magnus Eriksson Can you please explain the way to proceed 'Then make a new request to that page'.I didn't get the idea

Comment: You're currently making a request to the login page and you're also storing the cookies (which probably includes a session cookie). When that's done, you simply make another curl request to the page you want (personal_info.php) where you pass along the cookies you've just stored.

Comment: @ Magnus Eriksson I made another curl request as follows.  $curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://mysite/shota/forms/personal_info.php'
));
$result1 = curl_exec($curl);
echo $result1; But this will give the output which occured when url is called without a login